Geth with Clef: "account_new" method fails, despite established IPC connection and namespace
Have extablished communication between Geth and Clef over IPC.
Clef is popping-up manual confirmation on "eth_accounts", I hit "y" and receive valid empty array response on my end.
However when trying to create an account I send either "newaccount" or "account_new", Clef won't pop-up anything and the response received from Geth is "Error 32601 method does not exist/is not available"
Any help greatly appreciated as to what is causing this strange issue.
Edited to add:
Reading  this clef manual
where "account_new" method is described
No rules enabled at this point, because Clef needs no rules at this point according to the manual.
Since IPC communication is establised between Geth and Clef, I am sending "account_new" command from Geth and expect Clef to react, since in logs it says namespaces=account, meaning any command sent from Geth containing "account" is handled by Clef. Is this correct?
None of HTTP communication required between Geth and Clef since the do it over IPC. Is this correct?
Clef start-up logs:
INFO [04-04|15:52:46.029] Using CLI as UI-channel
INFO [04-04|15:52:46.927] Loaded 4byte database                    embeds=268,621 locals=0 local=./4byte-custom.json
WARN [04-04|15:52:46.927] Failed to open master, rules disabled    err="failed stat on /home/ethereum/.clef/masterseed.json: stat /home/ethereum/.clef/masterseed.json: no such file or directory"
INFO [04-04|15:52:46.927] Starting signer                          chainid=1 keystore=/home/ethereum/.ethereum/keystore light-kdf=false advanced=false
DEBUG[04-04|15:52:46.928] FS scan times                            list="250.831µs" set=583ns diff="1.459µs"
DEBUG[04-04|15:52:46.930] Ledger support enabled
DEBUG[04-04|15:52:46.931] Trezor support enabled via HID
DEBUG[04-04|15:52:46.931] Trezor support enabled via WebUSB
INFO [04-04|15:52:46.931] Smartcard socket file missing, disabling err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [04-04|15:52:46.932] Audit logs configured                    file=audit.log
DEBUG[04-04|15:52:46.932] IPCs registered                          namespaces=account
INFO [04-04|15:52:46.940] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/ethereum/.clef/clef.ipc
------- Signer info -------

intapi_version : 7.0.1
extapi_version : 6.1.0
extapi_http : n/a
extapi_ipc : /home/ethereum/.clef/clef.ipc

Yuri
